# Get height of item from another .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell in a UITableView. I programatically created a label with a height of 200 and a width of 50. When I do an `NSLog` in the `customCell.m` of the label's width and height, it gives me w: 50 and h: 200. But when I do an `NSLog` in `mainViewController.m` it gives me 0 for the height and width.

Not sure why it does that. I need to get the real height of the label in the `mainViewController.m`

Here's my code:

`customCell.m`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.label setText:@"Hello"];
    [self.myView addSubview:self.label];

    CGRect myFrame = self.myView.frame;
    myFrame.size.height = self.label.frame.size.height;

    self.myView.frame = myFrame;
    NSLog(@"%f", self.label.frame.size.height);  // Results: 200.0000
}
```

`mainViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    customCell *cellVC = [[cutsomCell alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%f, %f", cellVC.label.frame.size.height, cellVC.frame.size.height); // Results: 0.0000, 44.0000
}
```

I set`myView`to 0 in the storyBoard.

If you don't understand something, please ask and I will be happy to explain.

**Update**

Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.label setText:@"Hello"];
    [self.myView addSubview:self.label];
 view
    }
    return self;
}
```

`viewDidLoad`

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *customCell = @"customCell";

    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:customCell owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The problem now is that when I run the app, no cells get shown. But I do get the correct NSLog.

Comment: Where are you using custom cell? Have you subclassed your tablecellview? If you have subclassed and have linked in XIB storyboard file then you will be able to see its custom cell instance in cellforindexpath tableView datasource delegate method. Let me know I will help me to post right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mainViewController you just programmatically created the cellVC using alloc and then init, you did not create it from the nib,  like you did it in the customCell.m so the awakeFromNib method was not called on it.

**Update**
Change back to using the custom cell from xib (instead of registerCell)

```
 [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCellxib"
                     bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
     forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuseID"];    // in the viewDidLoad of the mainViewController
```

Then deque the cell - you do not really need to check if the cell is nil because dequeue is now guaranteed to return a cell

```
 CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCellReuseID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in your tableview datasource method

Keep the code currently in your awakeFromNib to initialize the custom cell added from nib.  The default cell from the xib is fully initialized here so you should be able to customize the custom view.  You do not need the initWithIdentifer anymore

You can optionally implement the table view delegate methods like:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // calculate the row height or return a constant
   return 200.0;
 }
```

Comment: It depends on what you want. You could read the customCell from storyboard with the correct frame dimensions, since you seem to be using storyboards, else you could use Xib file just for the custom cell and read the cell from the xib file, in that case the awakeFromNib method will get called.

Comment: I would like to do the first one, but I have to make some things programatially

Comment: initWIthStyle is in the customCell.m file or the mainViewController.m file

Comment: it should be in the customCell.m, you should use the same reuseidentifier that you used to register the cell and deque the cell in the mainViewController.

Comment: (I returned it to self.) The nslog did work, but then I get an error 'requesting the window of the view...' with different numbers. Note: I did change to the xib file. Sorry for going back and forth on that.

Comment: When I run the app, it crashes with that error. If you want I can post the full error? The error ends off saying 'This view Probably hasn't revived initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:.'

Comment: The problem is with the line of code I wrote in the viewDidLoad - '[self.tableview registerClass...' I get an error when I insert that. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I have updated the answer, there are many ways of doing what you are trying to do, if things don't work post the customCell file and the error that you receive

Comment: When you write @"customClass" do you mean the class of the cell or the cell id?

Comment: Well the "customCell" is the reuseIdentifier, it is also the cell id - sorry for the confusion.  I was asking to see the actual CustomCell.m file where you define the custom cell class.  Also you are not really using the xib file when you create the custom cell programmatically like this.

Comment: Couple of things I will update the answer to show that you need a height for table view row created programmatically secondly you do not need the xib file because you are creating the the custom cell programmatically not from the xib file

Comment: First - I added a row height, and nothing changed.  Second - The reason why I do need the xib file is because some things are being created in the xib/storyBoard, while others will be added programmatically.

Comment: Sorry I completely misunderstood the problem, I have updated the answer.  You will need to use the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method of the tableview delegate to return the height of the custom table view cell.  This method will only be called if you set the tableview.delegate property

Comment: The label still returns 0 in the mainViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that -awakeFromNib does not get called directly after -init

Try this:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
      return nil;
    }

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.label setText:@"Hello"];
    [self.myView addSubview:self.label];

    CGRect myFrame = self.myView.frame;
    myFrame.size.height = self.label.frame.size.height;

    self.myView.frame = myFrame;
    NSLog(@"%f", self.label.frame.size.height);  // Results: 200.0000

    return self;
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem of my question, but I don't see the label

Comment: You will need to programmatically create myView and add it as a subview in the init method of customCell

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: No There are multiple ways. I suggest you post a new question about this and provide details about what you are trying to do exactly.